# Trying to generify a logger factory in a functional manner

Tags: typescript, generics

I've read martin fowlers blog about [domain oriented observability](https://martinfowler.com/articles/domain-oriented-observability.html) and I'm trying to implement this idea without using classes. I've run into some difficulties involving generics in typescript.
This is my code (the error appears towards the end):

```js
import { Obj } from '../model/types';

interface Logger {

}

interface RouterLogger extends Logger {
    requestReceived: () => void
}

interface ExecutorLogger extends Logger {
    apiFound: () => void,
    templateLoaded: () => void
    apiExecuted: () => void
    apiRunEnded: () => void
}

interface TemplaterLogger extends Logger {
    templateRequestFired: () => void
    respondedSuccessfully: () => void
    respondedWithError: () => void
}

interface ApiLogger extends Logger {
    apiRequestFired: () => void,
    respondedSuccessfully: () => void,
    respondedWithError: () => void,
}

const loggers = {
    router: ({ data, metadata }: Obj): RouterLogger => ({
        requestReceived: () => {
            console.log('Request Received', data, metadata)
            // some rabbitMQ messaging
            // etc
        },
    }),
    executor: (context: Obj): ExecutorLogger => ({
        apiFound: () => { },
        templateLoaded: () => { },
        apiExecuted: () => { },
        apiRunEnded: () => { },
    }),
    templater: (context: Obj): TemplaterLogger => ({
        templateRequestFired: () => { },
        respondedSuccessfully: () => { },
        respondedWithError: () => { },
    }),
    externalApi: (context: Obj): ApiLogger => ({
        apiRequestFired: () => { console.log('request sent', context) },
        respondedSuccessfully: (response) => { console.log('success', context, response) },
        respondedWithError: () => { },
    })
}

function getLoggerDispenser<T extends Logger>(domain: keyof typeof loggers) {
    return (context: Obj): T => loggers[domain](context); //'RouterLogger' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Logger'
}

export {
    Logger,
    RouterLogger,
    ExecutorLogger,
    ApiLogger,
    getLoggerDispenser,
}
```

I hope the problem is clear - I'm sure there's a better way to export generic `Logger`s.
I'd be glad if someone helped me find It.

**EDIT**:
Please, notice that I'm using partial application when getting the logger, to be able to initialize the logger with a `context` which will make logging easier when all the data is already there.

**EDIT 2** (also see code above - I've added an example of using the `context`):
An example use case of this would be:

```js
const externalApiLogger = getLoggerDispenser('externalApi')({ jobId: 1, issuerId: 34 })

// send request
externalApiLogger.apiRequestFired()
// read response = success
externalApiLogger.respondedSuccessfully(response)
```

Comment: Is there a reason `function getLoggerDispenser<K extends keyof typeof loggers>(domain: K) { return loggers[domain]; }` wouldn't work for you?

Comment: My suggestion above does use generics and does allow `getLoggerDispenser("executor")(obj).apiFound()` while `getLoggerDispenser("externalApi")(obj).apiFound()` is an error.  If that works for you I'll write up an answer.

Comment: I don't understand; what specifically do you see as the difference between `context => loggers[domain](context)` and just `loggers[domain]`?  It's just [eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) (a function that just passes its argument to another function can be replaced with the other function).  Can you make a [mcve] where `context => loggers[domain](context)` cannot be replaced with `loggers[domain]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to make `getLoggerDispenser()` generic in the type of its `domain` input parameter, like this:

```
function getLoggerDispenser<K extends keyof typeof loggers>(domain: K) {
    return loggers[domain];
}
getLoggerDispenser("executor")(obj).apiFound(); // okay
getLoggerDispenser("router")(obj).apiFound(); // error
```

This behaves the same as your `getLoggerDispenser()` implementation in your example code, since `loggers[domain]` is always a one-argument function which takes an `Obj` input and returns a particular `Logger` implementation.  Returning `context => loggers[domain](context)` is essentially the same thing, with the possible exceptions of `this` contexts and/or `loggers` properties that are functions of multiple parameters, neither of which are present in the example code in this question.  If there is a meaningful difference between `loggers[domain]` and `context => loggers[domain](context)`, you might want to edit your example code to constitute a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the difference.

Still, if you do want to return `(context) => loggers[domain](context)` instead, you can do it, although the compiler won't be smart enough to verify that `loggers[domain](context)` has the specific return type necessary to identify which logger you're returning.  So we'll have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to maintain a strongly-typed return value:

```
function getLoggerDispenser<K extends keyof typeof loggers>(domain: K) {
    return (context: Obj) => loggers[domain](context) as ReturnType<typeof loggers[K]>;
}

getLoggerDispenser("executor")(obj).apiFound(); // okay
getLoggerDispenser("router")(obj).apiFound(); // error
```

Which still works.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-a8th2PYFUlUDqm4ddCVfIYjR3eE92AA8A0IG47iQsMYivFsoEQkRiwBcUvyTGCW21BFkVRMdMWxXFDkfHg-y1YkdWCPVqVpbdv3QNjCTgjdilEShsH6TlyDCXdigwo9pLwlZIyjYV-jFYEKNY59CJohU6OVRi1RYkChL0ziyQpXjDWg8yXDg04oH4TFKEkYByHhKAlGAd4ABFyFhF4iFEAAeABpHkSlsABrCAQDkMQiPACBEqtG0iCiUJMC7bAqEIcLIlUtxgH0UhKBQ8591gQ9JjzBwiAAbRyhg8soABdUI5MsSJsFsXxSvKq4UtC0BIDS+rRCa8L2qiAQzQtUs5EQDCUEEt1CAAIk2usvTYKBtp4fgfP8wLIHTURQk2iwt1ITbwlCZaA2zOY72sCJeCgOc5Bi7AQGO5hTqCi7SCuukQzuh6nvCF7byaTAPq+jtRENQQXJ2dzPIqySMwAcUBm0AuBkLSAiqKXlKOKEqSsbUqSybbSylq2oKorCRKsqKoZprmaodr5v4HG5Hx3zCbO4LLuu7JT2APJ7sew9YYaeHEe+37-qFkWgfOkmwadUR5ehpW3oR8JPrnFG8jRwQgA)

Comment: I'm not intending to question the use of partial function application; I'm advocating for eta reduction, which is different.  In terms of your fiddle, I'm absolutely not advocating that you use `sadLoggerWithoutContext()` instead of `happyLoggerWithContext()`; instead, I'm saying you should eta reduce the implementation of `happyLoggerWithContext()` [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/vx2putye/), and you can verify that it behaves exactly the same as yours. And the main reason why I am advocating for this is because the TS compiler understands it without needing a type assertion.

Comment: I've reread my answer and it's not obvious to me what part needs elaboration.  If something in there is unclear, could you let me know what it is?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't agree that it's irrelevant, so I'm not inclined to change the answer at this point.  Nor does it seem likely that we will come to an agreement on this matter, so I propose that we just leave this as is and move on.  Cheers!